# Powershell screen buffer

Tags: windows, powershell, console

i am using Windows Powershell, and just wondered if there is a way to scroll through the screen buffer (like for example in UNIX bash with SHIFT + PgUp / SHIFT + PgDn).
I know the there is a "more" command for paging through the screen buffer, but some keyboard shortcuts would be much more comfortable.

Is there any way to scroll the through the output without using the mouse?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [su] but is now too old to migrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scrollback is provided by Windows console itself, not by the shell inside (just like xterm and similar apps in Unix). And to activate its "scroll" feature, use **Alt+Space, E, L** as John Rennie described. (You could try the Scroll Lock key, but I can't test it myself here.)

Comment: Even for those of us familiar with the separation of such concerns in Unix, it's pretty hard to guess whether Windows will split things up the same way or not, so without already knowing the answer you wouldn't really know if it'd end up being PowerShell or just the Windows console in general.

Answer (score 3):

Press F7. Not the same as page up and page down but still very useful.

JR

Re Alexander's comment: oops, sorry I misunderstood your question. Irritatingly there isn't a simply keystroke to page up or down through the screen buffer. However if you use the comination alt-space, E L (i.e. select Edit/Scroll from the system menu) you'll find the arrows and page up/down scroll through the screen buffer. Press escape to exit the "scroll mode".

Maybe there is a hotkey to enter scroll mode, but I've been able to find it.

Comment: I know the F7 key. But please note that i don't want to navigate through the command history. I just want to seen the output of the commands executed last (if it doesn't fit on a single screen).

Comment: See my edit: it's a bit long to squeeze into a comment

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 Powershell use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll by line.

In Windows 10 cmd use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd> to scroll by line.

Comment: And it looks like plain PgUp/PgDn work to scroll by screenful in PowerShell, too!

Answer (score 1):

Just hold ctrl and push the up or down arrow. That works for me in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> worked for me (and <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> did not).

Just wanted to add that after activating, the item in the menu becomes gray and can not be changed anymore, so you may wonder how to deactivate it again, which is pretty easy: press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

*Thought that this may save a little time for someone like myself*